# Unresolved reference: AndroidJUnit4 An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm a complete beginner to coding and Android Studio. I've been trying to follow along with basic "hello world" guides and to my dismay, I am having zero luck.

I keep getting error messages even when the code seems to be correct. I've tried searching for the fix, but I'm honestly not sure what to search for as I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

I believe that it is a Kotlin issue. I've tried reinstalling android studio, resetting the settings and ensuring updates are current.

**Code**:

```
fun main(args:Array<String>) {
   println("hello world!")
}
```

**Error log**:

> build failed  9 s 875 ms
>   Run build   9 s 583 ms
>   null
>
> C:/Users/guilder/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3 
>   app/src/androidTest/java
>   com/example/myapplication/ExampleInstrumentedTest.kt
>   Unresolved reference: ext
>   Unresolved reference: AndroidJUnit4 
>   An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Screenshots of code and error messages are discouraged; please edit your question to include the relevant code/error text in the question itself.

Comment: You could use a scratch file for your basic learning stuff. Press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Alt` + `Insert`, now scroll down and select `Kotlin`. There you can write hello world programs and such. Also, the hello world should be handled by the `Activity` class. If you just want to learn `Kotlin` for now, I would advise installing IntelliJ.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, it's a bit late, but, if you are still struggling with this issue, just delete file which leads to crash. This is

> C:/Users/guilder/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/src/androidTest/java
>   com/example/myapplication/ExampleInstrumentedTest.kt

file. Have a nice day!